# Find and replace with filename

Tags: find, replace

I have a large number of files which contain text. All files contain the word "replace" (no quotes). I would like to replace that word with the name of the file.

Example, filename is:  On Time.txt

Replace the word "replace" (no quotes) with "On Time" (no quotes).

Comment: Are all these files in the same directory ? Also, do you want to substitute _"replace"_ only if it's a "word" or anywhere this string may occur (e.g. if it's part of the word _"irreplaceable"_) ?

Comment: Good points I should have included. Yes, all files are in the same directory. And the file contents are minimal:  "replace" is meant to be replaced with something; "irreplaceable" does not occur in any of the files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for filename in "On time.txt" ; do
  replacement=$(echo $filename | sed -e 's,^.*/,,' -e 's,\.[^\.]*$,,')
  [ -f "$filename" ] && sed -i "s,replace,$replacement," "$filename"
done
```

To do all files in your directory, replace "On time.txt" with * like this:

```
for filename in * ; do
```

Note that here filenames must not contain commas (you can choose the character so that it does not appear in your filenames).

Comment: basename --suffix is not recognized in my distro.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on Ubuntu 15.10 and I didn't check. I replaced it with another sed, so that it should work even if you're not using bash (but @mmmint 's % is good too).

Comment: The sed will remove anything following a period in the file name. One could limit it to only three-character extensions if necessary (this will fail on "hidden" files like `.bashrc` for example)

Comment: This one was the winner for me. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Phydeaux if this was the best answer for you, you should accept it by clicking on the large tick to the left of the answer.

Comment: Downvoted from 0 to -1 . . . FOUR YEARS after the fact, by a brave anonymous contributor!

Answer (score 2):

I would use sed for that:

```
for f in *.txt
do
    fullfile="$f"

    # filename without path (on_time.txt)
    filename=$(basename "$fullfile")

    # remove extension of filename (on_time)
    filename_woext="${filename%.*}"

    # replace all occurrences of "replace" with "on_time" in file
    sed -i -e "s/replace/$filename_woext/g" $filename

done
```

Comment: `sed -i -e 's/replace/"$filename_woext"/g' $filename` will not expand $filename_woext, you need `sed -i -e "s/replace/$filename_woext/g" $filename`.

Comment: Wow, never thought I would have multiple answers within minutes! Both of these answers worked a treat, however I chose to adopt the one proposed by Law29 since the one by mmmint didn't seem to like filenames with spaces, though I'm sure someone sharper than I could tweek that. Thank you Both very much!

Comment: if you're using `basename`, you can just do `filename=$(basename "$fullfile" .txt)` to remove the path AND the extension at the same time.  Also, "$fullfile" is redundant, you already have the full filename in `$f`, so why assign it to another variable?  Simpler version:.  `for f in *.txt ; do filename=$(basename "$f" .txt) ; sed -i -e "s/replace/$filename/g" $f ; done`  or even `for f in *.txt ; do sed -i -e 's/replace/'$(basename "$f" .txt)'/g' $f ; done`

Comment: The example is not written for efficiency. Explanation has priority over efficiency.

Comment: Excessive complication undermines understanding.  My simplification was not for the purpose of efficiency, it was to remove all the distracting and unnecessary complication in your example.

Answer (score 1):

That is simple in ZSH:

```
$ for f in *.txt; do filename=`echo ${f:r}`; sed -i -e "s/replace/$filename/" $f; done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*" -type f | xargs sed -i -e "s/replace/On\ Time/g"
```

This will replace "all" text files under current dir(and subdirs) as you want.

If you want only in current directory and not in it's subdirs.

```
find . -name "*" -type f -maxdepth 1 | xargs sed -i -e "s/replace/On\ Time/g"
```

If you want to replace in a different directory from your current dir.

```
find /path/do/dir -name "*" -type f | xargs sed -i -e "s/replace/On\ Time/g"
```

Works for me on zsh shell. Should work on all else too.

Comment: OP says _"I have a large number of files"_... Do you think all those files are named `On Time.txt` ?

Comment: Good point. Sorry, I guess I didn't read the question fully.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `m4` macro processor:

```bsh
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

for name in *.txt; do
    cp -- "$name" "$tmpfile"
    m4 -P -D replace="${name%.txt}" <"$tmpfile" >"$name"
done

rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

This uses `m4` by creating a macro called `replace` with a value that is the name of the file with the `.txt` filename suffix removed.  Any time the macro `replace` is encountered in the file, it will be replaced by its value.

Note that this may produce unexpected results if you use any other `m4` macros in the files.  With `-P`, the `m4` macro processor will only recognize its built in macros if they are prefixed by the string `m4_`, e.g. `m4_dnl`, so accidental collisions should not happen often.